# Google displays wrong author info in search results

Tags: bug

The Google search ("firefox javascript console") result for [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525/17633) is:

> [image]

The user [John Conde](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde) is attributed as author, linked to [his Google+ profile](https://plus.google.com/113449879855602316039).

However, it’s not his question nor did he write an answer.

He commented the question two times ([1](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers#comment8446_8525), [2](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers#comment8450_8525)). And he protected it:

> protected by [John Conde♦](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde) Oct 12 '12 at 11:17

I’m not sure if the Webmasters Stack Exchange provides authorship markup/link relations explicitly, or if this is an error by Google’s algorithms? It probably (I did not check) has to do with the protection. If that’s the case, maybe we could change it in a way so that Google doesn’t mistakenly thinks the "protector" is the author?

Comment: Darn, that guy is a handsome fellow!

Comment: LMAO! `You got designer shades just to hide your face and You wear them around like you're cooler than me`

Comment: Now also reported [on SO Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192968/193139).

Answer (score 3):

This has happened in the past, however I can't seem to locate the reference. The issue is very simple, and alarmingly silly. Look at precisely what you quoted (emphasis mine):

> protected ***by*** John Conde♦ Oct 12 '12 at 11:17

Google is of the opinion that on pages that contain actual content, the word ***by*** can not imply anything other than authorship. They *had* fixed this a couple of years ago, so hopefully they'll re-glue whatever has come unglued subsequently.

It's basically seeing this:

> ***by John Conde***

As I said, *alarmingly* silly, as that's not a mistake I'd expect Google to make :)